# Object pooling on Android platform

Tags: android

When I coding a Java Application, should I create my own object pooling to avoid object creation.  From the Logcat, I see log message saying GC has kicked in a number of times.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, I really think it depends on the specifics of your application and the kind of objects you're using.  In the section on [Designing for Performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html) one of the 2 basic rules to follow is

> Don't allocate memory if you can avoid
>   it

But it again, I think it depends on what you're trying to do.  If you look through the Android source code, you can see many examples of pooling and re-using Objects. For example, in the [AbsListView.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java&q=AbsListView#Recyclebin&d=4&l=4360) it maintains a "recycle bin" of Views to re-use.

Answer (score 0):

The GC will kick in often enough - you don't have to worry too much about that.  If you are noticing performance issues (or OutOfMemory exceptions) then you could try object pooling but as long as you de-reference objects you no longer need, you should be fine.